# Why does false invalidate validates_presence_of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, validation

Ok steps to reproduce this:

```
prompt> rails test_app
prompt> cd test_app
prompt> script/generate model event_service published:boolean
```

then go into the migration and add not null and default published to false:

```
class CreateEventServices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :event_services do |t|
      t.boolean :published, :null => false, :default => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :event_services
  end
end
```

now migrate your changes and run your tests:

```
prompt>rake db:migrate
prompt>rake
```

You should get no errors at this time. Now edit the model so that you validate_presence_of published:

```
class EventService < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :published
end
```

Now edit the unit test `event_service_test.rb`:

```
require 'test_helper'

class EventServiceTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "the truth" do
    e = EventService.new
    e.published = false
    assert e.valid?
  end
end
```

and run rake:

```
prompt>rake
```

You will get an error in the test. Now set e.published to true and rerun the test. IT WORKS! I think this probably has something to do with the field being boolean but I can't figure it out. Is this a bug in rails? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: where comes EventServer from? (last code block)

Comment: oops! EventServer should be EventService... this is just a class that I wrote. Its not apart of rails or any other API.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

See the [API docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of)...

> If you want to validate the presence of a boolean field (where the real values are true and false), you will want to use validates_inclusion_of :field_name, :in => [true, false].

Comment: lol, just found this in the API too. I will accept this answer in a couple minutes (Its says I can't yet) thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 10):

```
validates_inclusion_of :your_field, :in => [true, false]
```

no longer works for some versions after 1.3.0 of the shoulda matchers when you are testing that only Boolean values are accepted by your model.

Instead, you should do something like this:

```
it { should allow_value(true).for(:your_field) }  
it { should allow_value(false).for(:your_field) }
it { should_not allow_value(nil).for(:your_field) }
```

You can see the discussion [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/179).

There was a partial fix for this that now warns if you are trying to do this [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/pull/428)