# Rails checkbox validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running into a validation error on a checkbox field (`Perishable can't be blank`) when the check box is unchecked. I can check the logs and see that "perishable"=>"0" gets passed when unchecked, and "perishable"=>"1" when checked. "perishable" is white-listed in the controller, and it all works when the checkbox is checked. What's going on here?

Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :perishable
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.boolean :perishable, :null => false
    end
  end
end
```

View:

```
= f.label :perishable
= f.check_box :perishable
```

Rendered view:

```
<label for="product_perishable">Perishable *</label>
<input name="product[perishable]" type="hidden" value="0" />
<input id="product_perishable" name="product[perishable]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are validating the presence of a boolean field which apparently creates problems when it is `false`.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883864/454094):

> If you want to validate the presence of a boolean field (where the real values are `true` and `false`), you will want to use `validates_inclusion_of :field_name, :in => [true, false]`.

Comment: I'd hoped that 6 years on this wouldn't be necessary and that `validates_presence_of :perishable` would suffice. It's a boolean after all and can only have one of two known values. Alas.

Comment: Current Rails, use: `validates :field_name, inclusion: { in: [ false, true ] }`