# Populating Rails table with seeds file - where seed data has a 'false' for intended value in a boolean column, record is not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Running Rails 4.2, with Postgres 9.1 on the local development machine. Attempting to seed a table with five rows, with five columns on each row. One of the columns is a boolean value. Problem is that I can't seem to load any records where the boolean value is not true. Following is the schema:

```
  create_table "institution_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "institution_type"
    t.string   "institution_code"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.string   "ownership"
    t.integer  "term"
    t.boolean  "nonprofit"
  end
```

In the seeds.rb file I have:

```
institution_types = [
  ["Public 4 Year", "P4", "Public", 4, true],
  ["Public 2 Year", "P2", "Public", 2, true],
  ["Private 4 Year Profit", "R4P", "Private", 4, false],
  ["Private 2 Year Profit", "R2P", "Private", 2, false],
  ["Private 4 Year Nonprofit", "R4NP", "Private", 4, true],
  ["Private 2 Year Nonprofit", "R2NP", "Private", 2, true]
]

institution_types.each do |type, code, ownership, term, nonprofit|
  InstitutionType.create(institution_type: type, institution_code: code, ownership: ownership, 
      term: term, nonprofit: nonprofit)
end
```

Note that I have also attempted variants with:

- quotes around the boolean values for the nonprofit column (i.e.
  "true", "false")
- nothing declared for the nonprofit column on the two records where the setting is false (i.e. `["Private 4 Year Profit", "R4P", "Private", 4]`
- 'nil' declared instead of 'false'

Regardless of how I attempt to load this data into the database, I'm only getting the records where the value for the nonprofit column is true. In other words, the first two, and last two, in the institution_types variable declared above.

This is really frustrating, and so far none of my searches on the interwebs or Stack Overflow are yielding solutions. I suppose I could load all records as "true" then go into the dB directly and change the records with SQL...but that's dumb.

Alternative is going to be ditching the boolean value for the nonprofit column and stating "Profit" or "NonProfit" as the two options. BUT...before I do that (or even if that turns out to be the best course) I'd like to know what the bigger picture rules are around getting boolean data into a database using seeds.rb.

Comment: Use `create!` to raise an error when the create fails, so that you can see why the record is not getting saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block is silently discarding the information you probably need:

```
institution_types.each do |type, code, ownership, term, nonprofit|
  InstitutionType.create(institution_type: type, institution_code: code,
    ownership: ownership, term: term, nonprofit: nonprofit)
end
```

Change `create` to `create!` and it will throw, probably telling you your issue.

Comment: Great suggestion. When I do that, I get the error message `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Nonprofit can't be blank`. That's so whether I use `false` in the record, or leave nothing there after the term value. So - I'm still unclear how to pass in the value false.

Comment: Ahh, then my crystal ball tells me you've added `validates_presence_of` on that field, right?  Take [a look at this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883823/why-does-false-invalidate-validates-presence-of).

Comment: Yeah that special case can be confusing.  You'll do it again in the future too, I promise.  I do it all the time. :)

Comment: I have no doubts about that! would never have thought to dig that far into the validations. Thanks again